# How can I kill session by using database link?

Tags: oracle

How can I kill session from one database to another database by using database link

I am using this SELECT :

```
select sid , serial# from v$session@kaash;
```

@kaash is database link

how can I kill session and use database link with the command

```
alter system kill session 'sid,serial#' ;
```

where I will use database link name in the kill session command or what is the way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, as far as I can tell; `alter system` runs in database you're currently connected to. If you look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-SYSTEM.html#GUID-2C638517-D73A-41CA-9D8E-A62D1A0B7ADB), database link isn't listed as an option.

If you successfully created database link, you know credentials of remote database user - the one that lets you access its objects. I, somehow, doubt that this is SYS (or any other user with DBA privileges). However, if it is, then you actually *can* connect to remote database as privileged user and kill session in that database, which is then *local* to you.

I don't see any valid point in letting anyone do that remotely.

Answer (score 2):

You simply kill the local session. That will end the remote session as well. Or, you log into the remote database and kill the remote session there. If there was some really odd and pressing reason why you'd need to kill the remote session from the local DB, you *could* do this by creating a procedure on the remote database that does the kills and call that procedure over the link. But I doubt there's a good use-case for that.

If you need to know what the remote session is, on the local databse use `v$session.paddr` -> `v$process.addr` and get the `spid`, and also use `gv$session.inst_id` -> `gv$instance.inst_id` to get the `host_name` of the local instance. Then go to the remote database and use those values against `gv$session.process` and `machine`. That's the remote session serving your database link connection.